# how to sort interger value from json using Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I'm trying to use `orderBy` functionality in angular, and order by `RollNo` but its not working please check my code below

**SCRIPT**

```
var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
  $http.get('http://localhost/angular/jason/index.php').success(function(data) {
      $scope.countries = data;
      data.RollNo = parseFloat($data.RollNo);
  });
});
```

**JSON**

```
data = [{
    "Name": "Kamal",
    "RollNo": "20",
    "Class": "Class 12"
}, {
    "Name": "Amar",
    "RollNo": "12",
    "Class": "Class 10"
}, {
    "Name": "Rajesh",
    "RollNo": "9",
    "Class": "Class 7"
}]
```

**HTML**

```
 <body ng-controller="CountryCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Roll Number</th>
        <th>Class</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="country in countries | filter:name | orderBy:'RollNo'">
        <td>{{country.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{country.RollNo}}</td>
        <td>{{country.Class}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `data.RollNo = parseFloat($data.RollNo);` that wont work, you need to loop throw object and do it.

You need to convert `RollNo` property of counrty object to number first then you can apply `orderBy`

**CODE**

```
var newArray = [];
angular.forEach($scope.countries, function(val, index){
  newArray.push(val);
  newArray[newArray.length-1].RollNo = parseInt(newArray[newArray.length-1].RollNo);
});
$scope.countries = newArray;
```

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UNCmtgEQbt3P11Q8Nfjp?p=preview)

Hope this could help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

seems like your code is not correct

in

```
<tr ng-repeat="country in countries | filter:name | orderBy:'RollNo'">
```

you have used `orderBy:'RollNo'` and `RollNo` with in single quotes. that's the issue

change that to

```
<tr ng-repeat="country in countries | filter:name | orderBy:RollNo">
```

and it will work fine.

here is the [Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zsvw6XJu5D7Ip3zLGCiY?p=preview)